# How to create an object oriented code to substitute many 'try' loops in python

Tags: python

I am repeating this code so i can **scrape** some news from a website. On weekends and holidays, the website is not refreshed, there are only news on workdays.

This is the solution i created for the code to get the previous workday news, but i know its not the right way to be programming.

```
import smtplib, ssl
import datetime, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException, ElementClickInterceptedException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://fiis.com.br/atualizacoes/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(2)

#here I try to close a new html popup that has been there since last week

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/button').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("NoSuchElementException")
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/button').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("NoSuchElementException")
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/button').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("NoSuchElementException")


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-type="date"]'))).click()

#here I try diferent dates, first a today minus 1, then today minus 2 ... until today minus 4

try:
    today = datetime.date.today()
    five_day = datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
    d_N1 = today + five_day
    d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    d_N1_3 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]')))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]').click()
except TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        today = datetime.date.today()
        five_day = datetime.timedelta(days=-2)
        d_N1 = today + five_day
        d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        d_N1_3 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]')))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]').click()
    except TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            today = datetime.date.today()
            five_day = datetime.timedelta(days=-3)
            d_N1 = today + five_day
            d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            d_N1_3 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]')))
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]').click()
        except TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException:
            try:
                today = datetime.date.today()
                five_day = datetime.timedelta(days=-3)
                d_N1 = today + five_day
                d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                d_N1_3 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

                wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]')))
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]').click()
            except TimeoutException or NoSuchElementException:
                driver.close()
                driver.quit()
```

If yesterdays news is avaiable, i dont need to get the previous day.

4 days wont be enough in the future, so a better solution can be thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could replace the try-blocks with this:

```
days_ago = -4
today = datetime.date.today()
for n in range(-1, days_ago-1, -1):
    five_day = datetime.timedelta(days=n)
    d_N1 = today + five_day
    d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    d_N1_3 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]')))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]').click()
        break
    except TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException:
        if n <= days_ago:
            print(f"failed to fetch data for any date")
```

This works by using a loop that will run for `n=-1, n=-2, n=-3, n=-4` and will continue until either all of the `n` values are exhausted, or until the `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` doesn't produce an exception (that is the only way the `break` statement can be reached).

Comment: I tried this code, but it got today's news, not yesterday's, wich is not the intention

Comment: Great, that worked to get yesterday's news. Thanks for the help!

Comment: would this work for xpath '/html/body/div[1]/div/button' with variants in [1] with '['+n']' ?

Comment: No, it doesnt change by date, but last week the button was [1] and yesterday i got an exception and saw that the button changed for [2], i just wanted to do this to prevent more code exceptions if button xpath changes again.

Comment: I tried th make an change to xpath button, and got TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: in general though, sure, if the page has an xpath that changes like that, you can definitely substitute a variable into part of that. You might want this: `xpath = f'/html/body/div[{n*-1}]/div/button` (need to multiply `n` by `-1` to flip the sign. The way I'm doing it here is using python `f-strings`, which you might not be using oif you got that TypeError. They are a newer feature, and worth the 15 minute investment to read up on. very handy.)

Comment: I will try that. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Put as little code as possible in the `try` block. None of the first five lines can raise either `TimeoutException` or `NoSuchElementException`, so they should come *before* the `try` statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
retrys = 5
for i in range(retrys):
    worked = false
    try:
        # code that might cause an exception
        ...
        # leave the loop 
        break
    except Exception:
        # maybe print here that we retryed
        pass
```

Then you don't need to add more complexity with object orientation at this point.